# How to bind a jQuery object containing strings to List<string>?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

This is hopefully a one liner.

I've read Phil Haack's article http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx and other questions, but those are about `<form>`s and using multiple names, rather than formatting a JS object for a `$.ajax()` request.

I have:

```
var elements$ = $('.someClass');
if(elements$.Length === 0){
    //no need for call to server if no elements on page
    return;
}

var elementsList = elements$.map(function (i, element) {
    return $(element).data('some-data-attribute');
})

var data = getOtherObjectContainingData();
//encode in a format that can be automatically bound to list
data.ListOfString = elementsList.get().serializeArray();  //THIS LINE
$.post("ControllerName/ActionName", data, handler);
```

with controller action

```
public JsonResult ActionName(SomeObject OtherObject, List<string> ListOfString)
```

I have tried serialize(), serializeArray() and can solve this with a CSV string, but I don't want to faff about with it if the Model Binder can automatically do it if the request is formatted correctly.

How do I go about binding `$('string', 'string', 'string')` properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create ListOfStrings as an array, then extend it as an object

```
data.ListOfStrings = $.extend({}, ListOfStrings);
```

Should do the trick but obviously I have no way of telling ;)

Comment: Brilliant, this creates `ListOfString[n] 'individualString'` in the POST for all of the elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [.toArray()](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) ?

```
var elementsList = elements$.map(function (i, element) {
    return $(element).data('some-data-attribute');
}).toArray();
```

The `.map()` method returns a jquery array, calling `.toArray()` turns it into a pure javascript array.

Comment: Yes, the POST form contains `ListOfString[] 'individualString'` (without an index) for each of them, despite the object appearing with indices in the Firebug inspector. `ListOfString` is `null` in the action.